# Python Regex Match Before Character AND Ignore White Space

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match part of a string that comes before '/' but also ignores any leading or trailing white space within the match.

So far I've got `^[^\/]*` which matches everything before the '/' but I can't figure out how to ignore the white space.

```
      123 / some text 123
```

should yield

```
123
```

and

```
     a test / some text 123
```

should yield

```
a test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a little bit tricky. You first start matching from a non-whitespace character then continue matching slowly but surely up to the position that is immediately followed by an optional number of spaces and a slash mark:

```
\S.*?(?= *\/)
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/fR73ON/1)

If slash mark could be the first non-whitespace character in input string then replace `\S` with `[^\s\/]`:

```
[^\s\/].*?(?= *\/)
```

Answer (score 3):

This expression is what you might want to explore:

```
^(.*?)(\s+\/.*)$
```

Here, we have two capturing groups where the first one collects your desired output, and the second one is your undesired pattern, bounded by start and end chars, just to be safe that can be removed if you want:

```
(.*?)(\s+\/.*)
```

#### Python Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"^(.*?)(\s+\/.*)$"

test_str = ("123 / some text 123\n"
    "anything else    / some text 123")

subst = "\\1"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /^(.*?)(\s+\/.*)$/gm;
const str = `123 / some text 123
anything else    / some text 123`;
const subst = `\n$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Hr3f2n/1/).

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Spaces

For spaces before your desired output, we can simply add a capturing group with [negative lookbehind](https://regex101.com/r/NBiUgw/1):

```
 ^(\s+)?(.*?)(\s+\/.*)$
```

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /^(\s+)?(.*?)(\s+\/.*)$/gm;
const str = `      123 / some text 123
             anything else    / some text 123
123 / some text 123
anything else    / some text 123`;
const subst = `$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/85DfUP/1)

[image]

Comment: (.*?)(\s+\/.*) does not work if the string starts with whitespace, what do you think about changing it to "\s*(.*?)(\s+\/.*)"

Comment: is there any particular reason for using (\s+)? rather than \s*.  They look the same to me. I am doing kind of research on regex, so kind of curious about people's preference?

Comment: @Peipei  "_They look the same to me._"  -- very different in fact.  The `\s+` demands that there is a space there, preceding `/`in this case. The `\s*` doesn't so the regex will match even without a space, for example for `abc/`. All examples in the question do have a space before the `/` so (in the absence of specific requirements) I'd consider `\s+` to be _correct_ here.

Comment: @zdim, what I want to compare is (\s+)? and \s*, not \s+ and \s*. Clearly (\s+)? matches no space.

Comment: @Peipei Oh, I didn't realize that `?` was a part of it. Then it looks like there is no difference between them, except possibly in efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution

**Regex**

```
(?<!\/)\S.*\S(?=\s*\/)
```

**Example**

```
# import regex # or re

string = ' 123 / some text 123'
test = regex.search(r'(?<!\/)\S.*\S(?=\s*\/)', string)
print(test.group(0))
# prints '123'

string = 'a test / some text 123'
test = regex.search(r'(?<!\/)\S.*\S(?=\s*\/)', string)
print(test.group(0))
# prints 'a test'
```

**Short explanation**

- `(?<!\/)` says before a possible match there can be no `/` symbol.
- `\S.*\S` matches lazily *anything* (`.*`) while making sure it does not start or end with a white space (`\S`)
- `(?=\s*\/)` means a possible match must be followed by a `/` symbol or by white spaces + a `/`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without a regex

```
my_string = "      123 / some text 123"
match = my_string.split("/")[0].strip()
```

Comment: Nice! A not very useful but interesting test case: `my_string = "   / something"`. Here the different approaches vary: your solution returns an empty string whereas regex returns `None`.